# Why should I use a proxy server with Kestrel?

Tags: apache, nginx, asp.net-core, .net-core

The official [MS-documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy) says that if I want to host an ASP.NET core app on linux I should either put an apache or nginx reverse proxy in front of it. However I cant find any reasons why I should do that.

Why should I do that? Why can't it just run on kestrel? Why is the reverse proxy needed?

Comment: Mainly because Kestrel isn't set up to be a full web server so it lacks a lot of basic functionality that you'll most likely need

Comment: Could you tell me the basic functionality which it does not support? I remeber that I red something about the missing security at kestrel, sadly I cant remeber where. Is this also a point?

Comment: Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x . It goes over some basic use cases

Comment: I have no clue why this was closed especially for the reason it got closed for..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kestrel is a very simple web server and doesn't offer the features of something like IIS, Apache, or Nginx.  If you want to do things like SSL, Load Balancing, Rate Limiting, etc adding an extra layer in front of it can come in handy.

Another benefit is you can host multiple applications on port 80.  Nginx will handle the requests on 80 and route them to the correct application running on the server.

See this for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel

Comment: Thank you. Could you maybe explain what is ment with "It provides an optional additional layer of configuration and defense."? Why is this only the case with a reverse proxy?

Comment: The idea behind Kestrel is to serve content as fast as possible, not be a full featured server.

Comment: Oh so it doesnt have any security features like "normal" webservers?

Comment: what kind of features are you referring to?

Comment: I really dont know any. The information that kestrel is not as save as apache would be enough. Is this the case?