# Web API as a windows service

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.8

So I'm creating a new .Net Framework 4.8 Web API in Visual Studio 2019 and I'm wanting to know how to create the API as a windows service? I can't seem to find any examples or online resources to do so. I can run the API locally in VS and it opens Chrome and shows the responses under the local IIS Server it spins up. How do I take this same project and compile it as a windows service while still using HTTPS?

Comment: If you're writing a brand new service, why use .NET Framework? Why not .NET Core (the more future proof option)? Web API lives on inside of ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems Self-Hosting ASP.NET Web API in a Windows Service Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854232/problems-self-hosting-asp-net-web-api-in-a-windows-service-application)

Comment: I can't use core because I have dependencies on .net framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Web API is [fully capable of being self hosted on top of OWIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api), and does not require IIS to run.

Web API self hosted is basically just a console app. So the techniques for turning a Web API console app into a Windows Service are the same as for any other .NET console app. You can use a service manager such as [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/), or [create a Windows service project directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) (by inheriting from the appropriate classes, pretty messy) or use a library like [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).

Note that it's generally not a good idea to directly expose this self hosted app directly to the public. IIS provides a lot of security benefits out of the box designed to protect against malicious requests. If you're planning to publicly expose it, make sure you stick a proxy in front of it that will fulfill those security needs.

Comment: TopShelf take care of the security issues? Also is there a list of the potential security issues when self hosting with OWIN/TopShelf?

Comment: @user616 No, TopShelf is simply a library that converts a .NET console app into a Windows Service. It has nothing to do with security. You can research "IIS vs self host" if you want to find out security benefits of IIS.

Comment: So im assuming i would create a new WebAPI project and changes the project output type to console app?

Comment: It'd probably be easier to create a new console app and then add Web API to it.

Comment: Security issues like?

Comment: @variable Please expand on your question, as I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: `IIS provides a lot of security benefits out of the box designed to protect against malicious requests`- what kind of security benefits please?

Comment: @variable Honestly, that's something you can research yourself. Request rate limiting, certificates, rapid fail protection, etc. See [Why should I use a proxy server with Kestrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837048/why-should-i-use-a-proxy-server-with-kestrel) and [When to use a reverse proxy with Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Very information. Thanks. `Only the reverse proxy server requires an X.509 certificate, and that server can communicate with the app's servers on the internal network using plain HTTP.` - does this mean that https redirection can be configured on iis and so the httpsredirection configured in my .net apps startup file is useless?

Comment: @variable It depends on whether your reverse proxy server supports that functionality or not. IIS supports it via the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/).

Comment: Assuming I don't use that IIS url rewrite module, then will the .net core be able to handle httpsredirection by itself (since the startup file has got use httpsredirection)?

Comment: @variable Yes, .NET Core can do anything it wants to the response, including issuing a redirect to tell the client to access the site at a different URL.