# Run ASP.NET Core 5 Web API without console window

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0, kestrel

Does anyone know which options we have to run an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API (with kestrel) on a Windows host without having the console window open/visible?

The thing is that the "host" will be a regular PC with other applications on it and users not only could see the console window but also close it.

Unfortunately running it on dedicated hardware is not an option (for now).

Comment: You can run it as a service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio  See this SO response as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58960607/web-api-as-a-windows-service